# SSL and TLS Version Control

Tags: ssl

In regards to SSL and TLS security, is it possible to run multiple versions of each protocol on a server? If so, i would assume you would have to tell the apps which protocol to use since there are multiple versions installed. If not, what options are there for a similar environment?

Example: Server 1 has TLS 1.0, 1.1, and 1.2 on it.

Comment: SSLv3 (which you should no longer use anyway) and all versions of TLS (1.0, 1.1, 1.2) use a compatible 'hello' format that **automatically negotiates** (and uses) the highest version common to both endpoints (on each session). There was even a trick that allowed seamless transition between SSLv2 and SSLv3-and-up back in the early noughties, but that has now mostly fallen by the wayside. (OpenSSL 0.9.8 did it until about a year ago, and 1.0.x still can if you tweak the build and config.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is certainly possible. Backwards compatibility necessitates it, some clients may not be able to talk TLS1.2, some may only be capable of TLS1.0, etc. The TLS protocol suite handles version negotiation in the server and client hello messages, so once the client is configured to use, say, TLS 1.2 only, it should be able to negotiate that version with the server. TLS Implementations such as GNUTLS and OpenSSL, which are widely used as the SSL backbone of popular server software such as Nginx, support such configuration trivially:

```
http {
    ssl_session_cache   shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_timeout 10m;

    server {
        listen              443 ssl;
        server_name         www.example.com;
        keepalive_timeout   70;

        ssl_certificate     www.example.com.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key www.example.com.key;
        ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
```